# Selecting location type or multiple email/phone fields in Reports

Tags: civireport, custom-reports, reports

Is it possible to select a location type for default contact reports, or is it just hard-coded to use the Primary address/email/phone? Also, would it be possible to list a report with multiple email addresses or phone numbers (e.g. a column for Home, Work, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question but for a CiviCRM only solution, I found that Extended Report has a Report `Extended Report - Flexible contact report` that does an aggregation of all the phone numbers.

As of version 5.8, you have to use the following PR to make it work : https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/pull/461

To use this method :

1. install [Extended Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) and patch with the PR
2. in Reports -> All Reports, create a `New Report` and choose `Extended Report - Flexible contact report`
3. choose the column `Phone`

You should have something like that in the phone column for each contact :

[image]

Comment: good on you for adding a better/newer answer

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment on CiviReports, but I know my way around Drupal Views enough to suggest that as an alternative option since it allows you to specify for each field/column which Location Type to use for the phone, email etc

And to ensure you only see a single row for John even if he has multiple Work Phones it looks like there are two approaches.

[Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module (not tried it) or

[Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) which requires you to create a separate View display for each phone type/location and then insert that as a column, so eg for Home Phone it would give you a list of all the person's home phone in the one cell - but that adds a fair bit of work if you have to do it for many variations of phone/email v home/work etc, ie one view display per combination so the first option might be the better one to try

Comment: This could potentially be an option but we occasionally have multiple email addresses or phone numbers in one location type, and when that happens with Views it creates multiple rows for the same contact -- setting the View's `Query Settings` as "Distinct" and "Pure Distinct" doesn't seem to affect it. Do you know of a trick for this case to ensure contacts aren't repeated?

Comment: you can create a View for the phone and then insert that as a column, so eg for Home Phone it would give you a list of all the person's home phone in the one cell - think it involves the https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view module and in the settings specify that it is to match based on eg contact_id, but that adds a fair bit of work if you have to do it for many variations of phone/email v home/work etc, ie one view display per combination

Comment: in case you don't get notified of the Edit i made, see above re the Views Merge Rows module which might be simpler for your needs. let us know if you try it and it helps.

Comment: Views Merge Rows is the bomb, I was not familiar! Drupal-specific answer but works for me in this case. Thx.

Comment: cool. thx for reporting back