# How to add a column in a membership report for a secondary email?

Tags: civireport, email, column

I need to run a report which has a column for a secondary email.

Answer (score 1):

Which CMS are you using? If Drupal, then one approach might be to use Views instead of CiviReport. See [Selecting location type or multiple email/phone fields in Reports](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9560/selecting-location-type-or-multiple-email-phone-fields-in-reports).